# Looping an object of objects and breaking on finding a particular value

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, for-in-loop

I have an object of objects that is generated that looks like this:

```
var objectofobjects = {
  "2": {
    "propertyx": "23",
    "reset": false,
    "propertyz": 6
  },
  "3": {
    "propertyx": "33",
    "reset": false,
    "propertyz": 8
  },
  "4": {
    "propertyx": "44",
    "reset": false,
    "propertyz": 10
  },
  "5": {
    "propertyx": "45",
    "reset": true,
    "propertyz": 12
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is construct an appropriate loop in JavaScript that iterates through the objects contained in the `objectofobjects` and checks on the property of `reset` on each property. If a value of true is found on a reset property, for example like in the code block above, I would like the loop to break and return a value of true.

Comment: Sounds like a simple `for` loop to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and explain the issue you're facing. also please note if order is important to you, you should use an array, not an object.

Comment: `for (key in objectofobject) { test if objectofobjects[key].reset is true, then return true }`

Comment: Thank you for your comments and observations. This indeed should be simple -see the accepted answer - but I am having a rough day and thats why I found myself on the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i in objs){
      var obj = objs[i];
       if(obj.reset){
            return true;
      }
}
```

Comment: This might seem like it should be simple but I found myself on Stack Overflow today because I was exhausted and full of brain fog. Thank you for your solution, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You welcome. You health is more important. Please rest if you are exhausted already. If you continue you might end up with lots of bugs in your code and this could lead to morw restless night.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Just navigate through object using for loop and check for 'reset' value in each object as below.

```
for (key in objectofobjects)
{
    if(objectofobjects[key].reset === true)
    {
        console.log('Found object whose reset value is true');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function checkReset(object) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (objectofobjects[key]["reset"] === true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#some` was invented for that:

```js
var objectofobjects = {
  "2": {
    "propertyx": "23",
    "reset": false,
    "propertyz": 6
  },
  "3": {
    "propertyx": "33",
    "reset": false,
    "propertyz": 8
  },
  "4": {
    "propertyx": "44",
    "reset": false,
    "propertyz": 10
  },
  "5": {
    "propertyx": "45",
    "reset": true,
    "propertyz": 12
  }
}

console.log(
  Object
    .values(objectofobjects)
    .some(
      ({reset}) => reset
    )
)
```